# AttributeError: ' object has no attribute 'current'

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

> Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current'.

'sign in' button should transition to 'home' page, but gives an error instead. please help me understand what's wrong here. i have several codes and i get different error every time:
it used to run perfect till i split login and home screens into two separate kv files and change the python code. it seems im doing something wrong.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
Window.size = [320, 600]



class ShopApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.load_all_kv_files()
        return

    def load_all_kv_files(self):
        sm = MDScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file('login.kv'))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file('home.kv'))
        return sm


ShopApp().run()
```

kv file

```
MDScreen:
    name: 'shop'
    md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    background_normal: ''

    MDLabel:
        text: 'Welcome'
        bold: True
        font_size: 30
        background_normal: ''
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.55, 'center_y': 0.9}
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: [0/255, 0/255, 0/255, 1]

    MDFloatLayout:
        id: GREEN
        pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.35}
        size_hint: 1, 0.7
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:[0/255, 147/255, 114/255, 1]
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                radius: [35, 35, 0, 0 ]

        MDFloatLayout:
            id: WHITE
            size_hint: 0.85, 0.7
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.45}
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 1, 1, 1
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [25]

            MDFloatLayout:
                id: USERNAME
                size_hint: .85, .14
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': 0.8}
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: [255/255, 147/255, 114/255, 1]
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                        radius: [15]
                TextInput:
                    hint_text: "Username"
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    multiline: False
                    cursor_width: '2sp'
                    cursor_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                    foreground_color: [0/255, 147/255, 114/255, 1]
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                    padding: 15

            MDFloatLayout:
                id: PASSWORD
                size_hint: .85, .14
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': 0.6}
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: [255/255, 147/255, 114/255, 1]
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                        radius: [15]
                TextInput:
                    hint_text: "Password"
                    password: True
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    multiline: False
                    cursor_width: '2sp'
                    cursor_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                    foreground_color: [0/255, 147/255, 114/255, 1]
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                    padding: 15

            MDTextButton:
                text: "Forgot password?"
                font_size: 15
                theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                text_color: [0/255, 147/255, 114/255, 1]
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.35, 'center_y': 0.48}

            Button:
                text: "Sign In"
                font_size: "15sp"
                size_hint: .4, .11
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.35}
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'home_screen'
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: [0/255, 147/255, 114/255, 1]
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                        radius: [13]

            Button:
                text: "Sign Up"
                font_size: "15sp"
                halign: 'left'
                size_hint: .4, .11
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2}
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                on_press: screen_manager.current = 'sign_up'
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: [255/255, 147/255, 114/255, 1]
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                        radius: [13]

    MDFloatLayout:
        id: ORANGE
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7}
        size_hint: 0.9, 0.15
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: [255/255, 147/255, 114/255, 1]
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                radius: [40]

        MDLabel:
            text: 'Login'
            bold: True
            font_size: 35
            background_normal: ''
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.85, 'center_y': 0.5}
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
```

```
MDScreen:
    name: 'home_screen'
    md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    background_normal: ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your root widget does not have an object named manager.

```
on_press: root.manager.current = 'home_screen'
```

this code refers to **root** which will return an object reference to your widget - possibly a Screen or some object that inherits Screen.

you need the above code to return a reference to your screen manager.  this is probably what your other line here does.

```
on_press: screen_manager.current = 'sign_up'
```

you can use app.something to reach a method in your app and you can use root.something to reach a method in your widget class instance.

it will help you to retain a reference to your screen manager object in your app like this:

```
def load_all_kv_files(self):
    # create and retain a reference to my Screen Manager object
    self.sm = MDScreenManager()
    self.sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file('login.kv'))
    self.sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file('home.kv'))
    return self.sm
```

but you also need your build method to return a reference to your top level widget.

```
def build(self):
    _ = self.load_all_kv_files()
    return _
```